# How do I sign up for Pokémon go on my computer using a Google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

How do I sign up for Pokémon go on my computer with my Google account? I am confused, I can't really figure out how I can do it is there a website or something?

Comment: Uhhh, Pokémon Go is a mobile game. It uses Google Maps and your device's GPS. The whole point is that you have to physically go places. It doesn't make any sense for it to work on a computer.

Answer (score 6):

Pokémon Go is primarily a mobile game, you can find it on the [Android Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo), or the [iTunes Store](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/pokemon-go/id1094591345?mt=8). Setting it up on your computer has little to no use, as it's a game that requires moving around the world, and you cannot do that with a desktop computer (unless of course you strap a generator to your back).

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a Pokemon Club ID by using the link below, which can be completed on Mobile devices or PC.

https://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-trainer-club/caslogin

For it to use your google account, you need to use the mobile device in question.

You can use also use VM software such as Bluestacks to virtually create a mobile device on your computer and sign up through that.